# How to change a variable within a Spritekit action in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement a sequence of actions that includes a "wait" variable that changes as the score increases. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, but the objects that I am trying to spawn keep spawning with the same wait period even as the wait variable decreases. Here is my spawn function:

```
func spawn() {
    var waitDuration = TimeInterval(3.5)

    let setWaitDuration = SKAction.run({
        () in

        switch self.score {
        case 0..<5:
            waitDuration = 3.5
        case 5..<12:
            waitDuration = 2
        case 12..<25:
            waitDuration = 1
        case 25..<40:
            waitDuration = 1.7
        case 40..<60:
            waitDuration = 1.4
        case 60..<80:
            waitDuration = 1.2
        default:
            waitDuration = 1.0
        }
    })

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: waitDuration, withRange: 0.5)
    let spawn = SKAction.run(createAsteroid)
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, setWaitDuration, wait])
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequence), withKey: "actionKey")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never recalling spawn() therefore the wait variable is never going to change. Your run action gets created with the score variable set the first time this func runs. That action is saved with that score and will never get changed.

You could use recursion, to solve this problem. and have the action just recall the func, that way the waitDuration gets set properly

```
func spawn() {

    var waitDuration: Double!

    switch self.score {

        case 0..<5:
            waitDuration = 3.5
        case 5..<12:
            waitDuration = 2
        case 12..<25:
            waitDuration = 1
        case 25..<40:
            waitDuration = 1.7
        case 40..<60:
            waitDuration = 1.4
        case 60..<80:
            waitDuration = 1.2
        default:
            waitDuration = 1.0
    }

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: waitDuration, withRange: 0.5)
    let spawn = SKAction.run(createAsteroid)
    let rerun = SKAction.run { self.spawn() }
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, wait, rerun])
    run(spawnSequence, withKey: "actionKey")
}
```

> Edit removed repeat forever

Comment: This works for adjusting the wait variable but it also causes the spawn function to be called multiple times and the spawning increases exponentially.

Comment: removed the repeat forever on the last line, try now